# associations c#

Tags: c#, class, associations, diagram

Im trying to make an assosiation between two classes in c#.  The association is an nessesity one end from one class (class house) to and 1 .. * end in another class (class room).  In other words data from class room can be used in class house 1 to many times, but it needs to used at least once.

e.g. a room can only have one house, but a house must have at least 1 room or many.

I have this so far but it doesnt seem to create an instance of an object..

```
 class house
 {
    string name;
    int house_num;

    list<room> rooms;

    public house()
    {
      rooms = new list<room>();
      rooms.Add(new room());
    }
 }

 class room
 {
   int num_of_rooms;

 }
```

This is what i then call in the main cs file..

```
 house 94 = new house();
 room bedroom = new room();

 house.addRoom(bedroom);
```

So im basically trying to say a house has to have at least one room but it can alos have as many rooms as you could think off.  For some reason the abbove doesnt seem to like the 'addRoom' part of the code.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: `house 94 = new house();`? Does this even compile?

Comment: May be unrelated but variable names can't start with a number - change "94" to "house94" or whatever makes sense

Comment: House doesn't have an addRoom() method.

Comment: You first say `0..*` and later 'house to have at least one room'. which one is true?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code that I don't know where to start... I'll try and put an answer up though.

Comment: What errors are you getting. First thing I see is you can't have an object named `94`. Secondly, I don't see an addRoom method.

Comment: the house class should also have an addRoom method....  assuming a() should be the house() constructor, you're still missing the method.

Comment: `doesnt seem to like the 'addRoom' part`. do you expect compiler to create implementation for this function on its own, just deducing the logic from the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some good examples here but here is a fully functioning Console example to help guide people new to C#. This isn't gospel or best practice as I am trying not to confuse beginners but I've included a simple example of most things (readonly field means can only be set by the Constructor, a simple Property etc) but a good starter I hope!

```
namespace Example.ActualApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Program
    /// </summary>
    internal class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a new house with a bedroom
            Room bedroom1 = new Room("Master bedroom");
            House sampleHouse = new House("My house", bedroom1);

            // Add a room
            Room sittingRoom = new Room("Main sitting room");
            sampleHouse.AddRoom(sittingRoom);

            // Wait for user to press a button
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nFinished, press a key to end.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// House class
    /// </summary>
    internal class House
    {
        // Private fields
        private readonly string _name = string.Empty;
        private List<Room> _rooms = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="House"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the house.</param>
        /// <param name="room">The default room.</param>
        public House(string name, Room room)
        {
            // Store the house name and initialise the rooms collection
            _name = name;
            _rooms = new List<Room>();
            Console.WriteLine("New house created called '{0}'", name);

            // Now add the default room
            this.AddRoom(room);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a room to the house.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="room">The room.</param>
        public void AddRoom(Room room)
        {
            _rooms.Add(room);
            Console.WriteLine("Room called '{0}' added to house called '{1}'", room.Name, _name);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Room class
    /// </summary>
    internal class Room
    {
        private string _roomName = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Room"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the room.</param>
        public Room (string name)
        {
            _roomName = name;
            Console.WriteLine("New room created called '{0}'", name);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Example property (never pass fields around)
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _roomName;
            }

            set
            {
                _roomName = value;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is basically what you need and what you can expand on:

```
// Define a class for a house
public class House
{
    // Constructor for the House class
    // This gets called whenever your code creates a "new House(...);"
    public House(Room room)
    {
        // Initialize the list of rooms.
        _rooms = new List<Room>;
        // Add the passed room to the list of rooms
        _rooms.Add(room);
    }

    // This a "backing field" for the property below it. It is a
    // private variable that stores information about the class.
    private List<Room> _rooms;
    // This is the property that exposes the above backing field.
    // This property only has a "get" method, which means that you can only
    // read the property value. However, you can still add rooms to the list,
    // even though that may seem like writing. The difference is that you cannot
    // assign a completely new list to the property.
    public List<Room> Rooms
    {
        get { return _rooms; }
    }

    // You can add methods to a class to perform a task.
    // The method below adds a room to the list of rooms.
    public void AddRoom(Room room)
    {
        _rooms.Add(room);
    }
}

public class Room
{

}
```

The constructor for the `House` class takes one room, so that upon creation of a House, one room is added from the start, e.g. `House94 = new House(new Room());`. You can add more rooms by calling `House94.Rooms.Add(new Room())`.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to confuse someone, who's obviously new to programming, with `Properties`. Just my two-cents. +1 for the answer nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually thinking about that too, but then again, properties are an essential part of C#.

Answer (score 0):

Looking past the other problems with the code, you could add a room or more in the constructor of class `house`, which would guarantee the house to have at least the rooms you specify there.

edit: it seems you already do this, I am not even sure what you're asking :p

Comment: all the code is accepted fine untill the line 'house.addRoom(bedroom);' it wont accept the 'addRoom' part of the code

Comment: @Tom That's because the method `addRoom` is not defined. At least, not that we can tell by looking at your code.